# Why is switch statement used in useReducer hook to manage state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

Let's take a look at the following 2 ways of using `useReducer` hook for state management, they both do the same thing: click add button to + 1 and click subtract button to - 1:

1. with switch:

```js
const myReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'add':
            return {
                count: state.count + 1
            }
        case 'subtract':
            return {
                count: state.count - 1
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const Reducer = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(myReducer, { count: 0 });

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'add' })}>Add</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'subtract' })}>Subtract</button>
            <p>{state.count}</p>
        </>
    )
}
```

2. without switch

```js
const Reducer2 = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useReducer(
        (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
        { count: 0 }
    );
    
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setState({count: state.count + 1})}>Add</button>
            <button onClick={() => setState({count: state.count - 1})}>Subtract</button>
            <p>{state.count}</p>
        </>
    )

}
```

Which one is a better way of managing the state? I prefer 2 because it is simpler, allows us to manage state in a 'class component' way. I don't understand why 1 is needed: it needs a switch statement which is complex; if one wants to add state, a new case is needed. This all seems pretty cumbersome.

EDIT: I know this is a trivial example which has no need to use `useReducer` and `useState` is better, but what I really want to discuss is that when there are multiple states, which one is better?

Comment: I never needed `useReducer` and I think it's ugly but for the second case why not using `useState`?

Comment: It's just a preference that's become a convention. Write what you find most readable.

Comment: This is probably subject to opinion. But I think both versions have their place. The former has a more complex reducer function but as a consequence, each call to `setState` is a lot simpler, and also offers protection against setting the value incorrectly. The latter version is more flexible but also makes it easier to introduce a bug. Which is more appropriate will vary based on use case and is also subject to the programmer's taste.

Comment: Your 2nd way is simpler because your current use case is incredibly simple. So simple that even using `useReducer` is unnecessary, you should just use `useState`. For most use cases of internal component state, `useState` would be sufficient. You'd only look at using `useReducer` is you start getting all sorts of complex, pre-defined state changes - then, having a nice simple and clearly named case for each of these actions can be more digestible and less error prone. Also, `useReducer` is useful for things like context, where you may want to "dispatch" state changes from all over your app

Comment: Please see edit, the above example is trivial but what if there are multiple states?

Comment: sometimes you want to do more things rather than updating the state when a component mutates the state. Based on the "action", you might want to do things like fetch something async or trigger an analytic event or whatever. You want more control over what is changing then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch statements are typically used in `useReducer` as a remnant from reducers in redux.

Your second example is a good way of using an approximation of `this.setState` in a function component, since `useState` is only really designed for a single value as there is no shallow merging of the old state and the new. I have extended this to one step further at the end of this answer.

As for your question of which is best to manage state in a `useReducer`, it really depends on what you want to use it for and how. You aren't just limited to those two types of things: you can use anything in them. I've had good luck using [redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)'s createSlice in a `useReducer` for a type-safe reducer with Immer to make immutability easier.

> I don't understand why 1 is needed: it needs a switch statement which
> is complex; if one wants to add state, a new case is needed

If you write a reducer case for each part of the state, yes. It is super cumbersome and I would definitely do it a different way. The best way to use the first approach is when you have more complicated situations you need to work with or generic ways to work with more state options.

As written in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

> useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex
> state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state
> depends on the previous one. useReducer also lets you optimize
> performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can
> pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.

They are a *very* powerful addition to function components and allow for an easier way to work with complex logic or values that are connected logically. Whether you use it or not is of course up to you and anything that is done with `useReducer` can be done with `useState`s with varying amount of boilerplate and logic.

For a generic way to work with a lot of state properties:

```js
const { useRef, useReducer } = React;
const dataReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'toggle':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.name]: !state[action.name],
      };
    case 'change':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.name]: action.value,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
function Example() {
  const [data, dispatch] = useReducer(dataReducer, {
    check1: false,
    check2: false,
    check3: false,
    input1: '',
    input2: '',
    input3: '',
  });
  const throwErrorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleChange = function (e) {
    const { name, value } = e.currentTarget;
    dispatch({ type: 'change', name, value });
  };
  const handleToggle = function (e) {
    const { name } = e.currentTarget;
    dispatch({ type: 'toggle', name });
  };
  const checkBoxes = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3'];
  const inputs = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3'];
  return (
    <div>
      {checkBoxes.map((name) => (
        <label>
          {name}
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={name}
            onChange={handleToggle}
            checked={data[name]}
          />
        </label>
      ))}
      <br />
      {inputs.map((name) => (
        <label>
          {name}
          <input
            type="text"
            name={name}
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={data[name]}
          />
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

As for slightly more complex logic, here's an example for a data fetch:

```js
const { useRef, useReducer } = React;
const dataReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'fetchStart':
      return {
        loading: true,
        data: null,
        error: null,
      };
    case 'fetchError':
      if (!state.loading) {
        return state;
      }
      return {
        loading: false,
        data: null,
        error: action.payload.error,
      };
    case 'fetchSuccess': {
      if (!state.loading) {
        return state;
      }
      return {
        loading: false,
        data: action.payload.data,
        error: null,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
function Example() {
  const [{ loading, data, error }, dispatch] = useReducer(dataReducer, {
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    error: null,
  });
  const throwErrorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleFetch = function () {
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch({ type: 'fetchStart' });
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'fetchSuccess', payload: { data: { test: 'Text' } } });
    }, 5000);
    throwErrorRef.current = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      dispatch({ type: 'fetchError', payload: { error: 'Oh noes!' } });
    };
  };
  const handleFetchError = function () {
    throwErrorRef.current && throwErrorRef.current();
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFetch}>Start Loading</button>
      <button onClick={handleFetchError}>Throw an error in the fetch!</button>
      <div>loading: {`${loading}`}</div>
      <div>error: {error}</div>
      <div>data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

A simple one I've had use of is a force update that just increments a value to cause the component to re-render.

```
const [,forceUpdate] = useReducer((state)=>state+1,0);
// Example use: forceUpdate();
```

I modified your example 2 to add support for the function method of updating the state so it's closer to a full `setState` knockoff using `useReducer`. I can't think of a decent way to make the callback work (the second parameter in `this.setState`)

```js
const { useRef, useReducer } = React;
const stateReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    action = action(state);
  }
  return { ...state, ...action };
};
const useMergeState = (initialState) => {
  return useReducer(stateReducer, initialState);
};
function Example() {
  const [state, setState] = useMergeState({
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    error: null,
    count: 0,
  });
  const throwErrorRef = useRef(null);
  const handleFetch = function () {
    if (state.loading) {
      return;
    }
    setState({ loading: true });
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setState({
        data: { text: 'A super long text', loading: false, error: null },
      });
    }, 5000);
    throwErrorRef.current = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      setState({ error: 'Oh noes!', loading: false, data: null });
    };
  };
  const handleFetchError = function () {
    throwErrorRef.current && throwErrorRef.current();
  };
  const incrementCount = function () {
    setState((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 }));
    setState((state) => ({ count: state.count + 1 }));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFetch}>Start Loading</button>
      <button onClick={handleFetchError}>Throw an error in the fetch!</button>
      <div>loading: {`${state.loading}`}</div>
      <div>error: {state.error}</div>
      <div>data: {JSON.stringify(state.data)}</div>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>increase count by 2</button>
      <div>count: {state.count}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```